# Convert resume to editable format

Tags: resume, latex2rtf, altacv

For my resume I use [AltaCV](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV) format. I normally convert latex template to pdf, however this time possible employer requires editable format, specifically docx, rtf or odt. I'm happy with my current latex template so I would very much like to avoid necessity to search for a new one in other editor.

I tried using [latex2rtf](https://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/), however it doesn't seem to correctly process more complicated, multi-file resumes.

Is it possible to use latex2rtf to convert this resume template? Or is there some other way to convert to editable format?

Comment: You could try Pandoc, it converts to many formats among which docx and odt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try using PDF to Word converters. I tried iLovePDF's converter with an AltaCV example PDF and the results were not bad:

[image]

You could use this as an starting point and fine-tune it as you like. Maybe there's a better converter. I've tried Word's and Google Doc's converter and the results were janky.

Comment: This worked way better than I expected, barely anything to correct after conversion. Thanks